# list of resource doesn't display in Jersey using XML format

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to make a small program that will display a list of aliens in xml format on the web.

I have 3 files:

1. alienRepository class- demo database
2. Alien class
3. alienResource class

this is what I type:

http://localhost:8085/Rest/webapi/aliens

I am getting the following error in the browser:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

I don't see the list in the browser but in the console I see the printout ("getAlien called.....");
what am I doing wrong?

```
public class AlienRepository {
    List <Alien> aliens;
    public AlienRepository() {
        aliens = new ArrayList<>();

        Alien a1 = new Alien();
        a1.setName("Ohad2");
        a1.setPoints(60);
        a1.setId(1);

        Alien a2 = new Alien();
        a2.setName("Ohad");
        a2.setPoints(80);
        a2.setId(2);

        aliens.add(a1);
        aliens.add(a2);


    }

    public List<Alien> getAliens(){
        return aliens;
    }

    public Alien getAlien(int id) {

        for (Alien a: aliens)
        {
            if(a.getId() == id)
                return a;
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {

    private String name;
    private int points;
    public int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    } 
}
```

---

```
@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResource {
    AlienRepository repo = new AlienRepository();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Alien> getAlien() {
        System.out.println("getAlien called.....");
        return repo.getAliens();
    }
}
```

this is the servlet mapping:

```
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Is there any exceptions being logged? If not, use an [ExceptionMapper<Throwable>](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6352) to try to catch it and print the stack trace. If you get a stack trace, please add it to your post.

Comment: OK, I ll try to use it later and update. thanks.